# How to pass parameters from cordova HTTP to Spring controller

Tags: java, angular, spring, ionic4, ionic-native

In my ionic 5.0.0 application I'm using cordova's native HTTP to make the rest calls. Below is the code snippet of my logout function.

But when i execute this function i'm getting following error.

> "advanced-http: \"data\" argument supports only following data types: String"

```html
  logout() {
    this.setData("url", "/web/oauth/revoke-token");
    let apiUrl = this.getBaseUrl() + this.getData("url");
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Basic Y2hyR3liUnBxQUR3X2VDemw5dzc0cHU4dXNnYTpKdmZ1azgyYnBUQlVnNDJ6NU1hZFhXOWJPeElh'
    };
    const params = {
      'companyId': this.getData("COMPANY_ID"),
      'token': this.getData("ACCESS_TOKEN"),
      'client_id': this.getData("CLIENT_ID"),
      'token_type_hint': 'access_token'
    };
    this.nativeHttp.post(apiUrl, params, headers).then(response => {
     console.log("success response: "+response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error response: "+error);
    });
    console.log("finished");
  }
```

Here is my Spring controller which receives the params.

```html
 @RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<Object> logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String clientId = request.getParameter(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_ID);
  String token = request.getParameter(OAuth2Constants.TOKEN);
  String tokenTypeHint = request.getParameter(OAuth2Constants.TOKEN_TYPE_HINT);
  String companyId = request.getParameter(WebConstants.COMPANY_ID_PARAMETER);
    }
```

But unfortunately all params receives in the controller as null.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution for the issue. Simply set the data serializer for http request as follows before doing the post call.

```
this.nativeHttp.setDataSerializer( "urlencoded" );
```